# Why did Jesus go to Galilee from Judea when John was arrested if Herod Antipas was the tetrach of those regions. Matthew 4:12

Tags: john, jesus

My Bible has footnotes and in the footnote for Matthew chapter 4:12 it says:

> John had been arrested by Herod Antipas (see 14:1-12) Antipas was tetrarch of Galilee and Perea, where John was probably working at the time... Jesus withdrew to avoid martyrdom before finishing his work of revealing the kingdom.

My question is why would Jesus go to Galilee if he was trying to escape martyrdom when Herod Antipas was the tetrarch ruling over those regions?

Comment: Please identify your Bible.

Answer (score 4):

Benson holds another view about the possible reasons for Jesus departure into Galilee as described in Matt 4:12 -

> Matthew 4:12. Now when Jesus had heard that John was cast into prison
> — Namely, for reproving Herod Antipas, tetrarch of Galilee, for taking
> his brother Philip’s wife, and for other evils, Matthew 14:3-4 : he
> departed into Galilee — Viz., from Judea. This it seems he did, partly
> to avoid the envy of the Pharisees, John 4:3, and partly to encourage
> John’s disciples, and to continue the preaching interrupted by his
> confinement, being desirous to improve those good impressions which
> the ministry of John had made on the minds of the people, and which
> would not be erased but deepened by the injurious things they saw him
> suffer. Thus it becomes one messenger of God to carry on the work
> begun by another.

Similarly, Barnes observes this:

> He departed into Galilee - See Matthew 2:22. The reasons why Jesus
> then went into Galilee were probably:
>
> 1. Because the attention of the people had been much excited by John's preaching, and things seemed to be favorable for success in his own
>    ministry.
> 2. It appeared desirable to have some one to second John in the work of reformation.
> 3. It was less dangerous for him to commence his labors there than near Jerusalem. Judea was under the dominion of the scribes, and
>    Pharisees, and priests. They would naturally look with envy on any one
>    who set himself up for a public teacher, and who should attract much
>    attention there. It was important, therefore, that the work of Jesus
>    should begin in Galilee, and become somewhat established and known
>    before he went to Jerusalem.

I agree that the footnote from the OP's Bible is a little mystifying.

Comment: Good answer.  The other side of the coin is the adult Jesus didn't seem to have a problem with political leaders.  Herod Antipas didn't want to kill John the Baptist and thought Jesus was John come back to life.  Pilate, a polytheistic Roman, was scared when the Jewish leaders said he claimed to be the Son of God.  Both undoubtedly heard about Jesus' miracles.

Answer (score 0):

I came here to try to understand why it said Jesus "withdrew"; that word was really confusing because it implies going away from something. However, and reading what is written here in this thread my understanding is this (please tell me if this makes sense or not): Jesus was there in Nazareth his hometown, but above in the post it says, "Judea was under the dominion of the scribes, and Pharisees, and priests", and "Because the attention of the people had been much excited by John's preaching". This got me thinking about the holy spirit today, and how Jesus talked about what's in a man's heart many times. My understanding is that Jesus was there amongst His own people, so rightly and justly He would try to give the good news to them, but it was a land governed by the Pharisees, scribes, and priests thus their hearts were hardened by their pride and arrogance in their own knowledge. In Galilee, however, John had been preaching already and the people's hearts were open and hungry much as the holy spirit does today. He did what was right and tried to give them the good news, but he "withdrew" from them and went to where there were open and willing hearts after John went to prison because those people needed Him and their hearts were open. Behold, I stand at the door and knock. If anyone hears my voice and opens the door, I will come in to him and eat with him, and he with me. Revelation 3:20

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Answer (score 0):

He submitted to the Father. Therefore the Father must have told Him to go there, and He went in trust that He would receive any instruction and protection He needed.

John 5:19 (KJV):

> Then answered Jesus and said unto them, Verily, verily, I say unto you, The Son can do nothing of himself, but what he seeth the Father do: for what things soever he doeth, these also doeth the Son likewise

Answer (score 0):

Jesus went to Galilee to fulfill prophecy.  Isaiah 9:1-2.  It also placed Him in the direct path of selecting His disciples Simon Peter and Andrew.  Matthew 4:18-21. He went along further and James and John, sons of Zebedee. Matthew 4:21-22

Answer (score 0):

Considering the prophecy of Isaiah in_Isaiah 9:1_2 then verse 4. Related to Matthew 4:16 I saw the arrest of John the Baptist, was the end of his ministry and purpose on earth. And Jesus Christ seeing the end of John the Baptist in his arrest, moved towards the fulfillment of his own mission on the earth,  first know that Jesus was not on the earth for the already righteous. But the ones who dwells in darkness. Now connecting Isaiah 9:2 to Matthew 4:17 and 19 . you will agree with me that Jesus Christ saw the end fulfilling John the Baptist ministry , and moved to the fulfillment of prophet Isaiah.

Comment: Welcome to BHSE and thanks for your contribution. I think you have made a good Bible insight, but the question involves "Galilee"; "Judea" and "Herod Antipas". Can you edit your answer to include mention of these so that we can see clearer relationship of question to answer? Do take the tour to see information on how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

The footnote in the OP's Bible is groundless. Nobody can hurt a man who God is with him. This has been proven the Nazarene couldn't push Jesus off the cliff (Luke 4:29-30). With the same reason, Jesus went to Galilee should not be afraid of king Herod, neither he afraid of the Jewish leaders. Most likely was to fulfill the prophesy Isaiah given 700 years ago

> Nevertheless, there will be no more gloom for those who were in distress. In the past he humbled the land of Zebulun and the land of Naphtali, but in the future he will honor Galilee of the nations, by the Way of the Sea, beyond the Jordan— (Isaiah 9:1 NIV)

Why is the Lord choosing Galilee as the starting place of restoring Israel? The scripture does not give an explanation. Reviewing the whole Bible, we may notice that the united kingdom was first deteriorated from the northern kingdom, and subsequently conquered by the Assyrians was from the north, that is, Galilee was the place first fallen to the Gentile. It might be from where it fell, from where it would begin restoring.

John the Baptist was the one who *'make straight the way for the Lord' (John 1:23; Isaiah 40:3)*. In John 3:22-30, the disciples of John were concerning people were going to the disciples of Jesus for baptism (John 3:26). John the Baptist replied them: *"He must become greater; I must become less.” (John 3:30 NIV)*. By then, John the Baptist was likely completing his mission given by God.

John the Baptist was arrested could be a sign the job of John completed and Jesus missionary fully took over, and He had to start from Galilee.

Answer (score 0):

In Matthew ch3 v13, Jesus came from Galilee to meet John in the Jordan region.

My reading of the geography is that the "withdrawal" of Jesus was away from the Jordan region and back home, because it was in the Jordan region that officers of Herod might be looking for the friends of John.